# Perl DBI - DB2 : fetchrow failing for 0 records

Tags: perl, select, db2, dbi

I'm migrating AIX scripts to Linux.
In a particular script

```
$sql_stmt6 = "SELECT CHAR(DATE(MAX(TIMESTAMP)),USA) FROM SCHEMA.TABLENAME WHERE COL1 = 194 and COL2 ='P'";
$sth6= $dbh1->prepare($sql_stmt6);
$sth6->execute();
while (@rows = $sth6->fetchrow)
{
    $var = $rows[0];
    $var =~ s/\s+$//;
    print "var = $var\n";
}
$sth6->finish();
```

The fetchrow works fine when the select returns a row, but if the select gives 0 records, 
the fetchrow throws the follwing error:

***Error: Data in column 0 has been truncated to 10 bytes.  A maximum of -1 bytes are available at ./test.pl line 46***

Please help...thanks...

Comment: Obviously you have to make a negative length string.

Comment: sorry didn't understand you... can you explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is to use `fetchrow_array`, [as shown in the DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array).  The documentation clearly explains what the behavior should be when no row is returned.

I'm not sure what `fetchrow` is.  I do see it being used in the example in the `DBD::DB2` documentation (and I presume that is why you are using it), but I can't see it documented anywhere.  My guess is this is either outdated or an internal function that bypasses the proper error handling.  Try switching to `fetchrow_array` instead.

**Other important considerations:**

Make sure to check for errors when you prepare and execute the statement:

```
$sth6 = $dbh1->prepare($sql_stmt6) or die 'Cannot prepare: ' . $dbh1->errstr;
$sth6->execute() or die 'Cannot execute: ' . $sth6->errstr;
```

Make sure to

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

if you are not already doing so (it looks suspiciously like you are not, as I don't see any variables declared with `my`).

Both of these steps will make it much easier to catch errors.

And it will also help you a lot to use more descriptive names for your variables.  The name `$sth6` suggests you have at least six different statements with similar names in your code.  It will be a lot clearer if you name it something meaningful, like `$max_time_sth`.

Comment: According to the source code:   "fetchrow      => undef, # old alias for fetchrow_array"

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues when connection to AIX or Zos databases, You need to experiment with the connection attributes, for me it was some foreign characters that were converted to utf8 that made the size of the column longer than the allowed size and then fetchrow_array and fetchrow_hash methods throw errors, the below settings fixed it:

```
LongTruncOk         => 1,
LongReadLen         => 2147483647,
```

You may also have to look at the DBD::DB2 specific connection attributes:

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-DB2/DB2.pod#Connection-Attributes